# Normalizing height data entered into excel columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm pasting some data into Excel columns and the data is in the format `6-5` for example, which represents a height.

How can I make it so when the data is entered Excel automatically turns it into `6'5"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the cell that you pasted the data in is formatted as Text (otherwise Excel would interpret "6-5" as a Date). If cell A1 contains `6-5` as text, you can enter the following formula in another cell to return `6' 5"` as text:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","'")&""""
```

The formula changes the `-` to `'` and then appends `"`. Note that in a formula, you must enclose text in double quotes, and if your text includes a double quote, you need to change the double quote to two double quotes, so `""""` in the formula just represents a single double quote.

**Edit to address OP's comments**

If you are pasting data into columns A through D, and the height is in column B, you can put the formula in column E (or some other column not overwritten by the paste. Now you can either:

1. Copy the cells with the formula and use Paste Special | Values to overwrite the heights in column B. **Or...**
2. Hide Column B (don't delete it) and you will still have the formatted heights in column E (or wherever you put the formula). **Or...**
3. Use Group from the Data ribbon to mark column B as a subsidiary column.You can then quickly hide and unhide the column using the "+" or "-" symbols above that column.

I prefer the 3rd method.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's formatted as Text. What do you mean by I have to enter the formula in another cell? Can't I just enter it in the respective cell the data is going to go into?

Comment: If you paste into the cell that contains the formula, you will overwrite the formula. In a case like this, you might want to do something like paste the heights in column A and put the formulas in column B. If you don't want to see column A, you can hide it after you paste into it. Alternatively, copy the cells with the formulas and use Paste Special|Text to replace the value in column A with the text produced by the formula, then delete the formula.

Comment: Hmm ok. That's rather irritating as I am pasting in multiple column data as in when I do a paste the data includes data for 4 columns and the height column is column `B`; I guess I'll have to create a new column somewhere else that uses the data entered into column `B` and then paste over it as you suggested?

Comment: That's right. I have edited my answer to show the options.